# Perform a query in Firestore where a field is in a array

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to obtain some docs from Firestore with a query that I thought I wouldn't have issues but I am not achieving it. I have some data in my state which looks like:

```
const favorites = [ "1_Test1", "2_Test2" ]

const collectionRef = collection( FirebaseDB, `users/${ uid }/scores` );
const q = query(collectionRef, where('id','in',`${favorites}`));

const [scores] = useCollectionData( q, collectionRef );
  console.log(scores)
```

But this is giving me an empty array. I have tried the following code just to test if it was arriving to Firestore:

```
const favorites = [ "1_Test1", "2_Test2" ]

const collectionRef = collection( FirebaseDB, `users/${ uid }/scores` );
const q = query(collectionRef, where('id','==','1_Test1'));
    
const [scores] = useCollectionData( q, collectionRef );
  console.log(scores)
```

And that worked just fine. It gaves me that particular document. So I am doing something wrong in the first query. I have tried several things like removing brackets but I don't get which is the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you use string interpolation in `` `${favorites}` ``. This converts `favorites` to a string, which Firestore then uses for the comparison.

To fix the problem, pass the array like this:

```
const q = query(collectionRef, where('id', 'in', favorites));
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I tried that and I don't get any results. When I go to the console I get the results just fine. I have made sure that in the collection I am pointing, every single document has the "id" field. I have also made sure that the ids in the "favorites" that I am providing are there (they appear just fine if I use the "==" to one doc. But when I try the "in" or the "array-contains" or similar I don't get any output. No error, just emptiness. If the problem would be an idex would I received some warning in the console?

Comment: There may be more mistakes in the code you shared, but this is definiterly one of them. --- Does the explanation of the mistake that I gave make sense? Does it explain why that would ensure your code doesn't work, and does is makes how the change in my answer would address that? ---

Comment: Indeed that was one of the mistakes that I had. I begin to think that the reason I am not getting any results or any error is because I would need an idex but I am not getting any message in console about it either. I will try to debug the issue and write a more explanatory and detailed question to see if I can get it. Thanks!

Comment: If it still doesn't work after fixing the problem I pointed out, it might help if you edit your question to show a document that you'd expect to be returned by the (updated) query.